# Generate values on Bigquery based on previous months

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like:

```
month | type | email
-----+------+------
2015-08-01    |   questionnaire    |   email1@gmail.com
-----+------+------
2016-08-01    |   creation    |   email1@gmail.com
-----+------+------
2018-12-01    |   buy    |   email1@gmail.com
-----+------+------
2020-02-01    |   questionnaire    |   email2@gmail.com
-----+------+------
2021-08-01    |   creation    |   email2@gmail.com
-----+------+------
2021-11-01    |   buy    |   email2@gmail.com
```

I want to generate a table that has, for all emails, every month since min(month) until current_date(). As for the type column, the value should be the "strongest" with questionnaire < creation < buy.

For example:

- if on 2018-08-01, I have a type buy, then all months until current_date() should have this type.
- if on 2017_12-01, I have a type qustionnaire, and then, on 2020-01-01 I have a creation type, then all month from 2017_12-01 until 2020-01-01 should be questionnaire type. Then, from 2020-01-01 until current_date, it should be creation type.

Any idea how to do it in bigquery?

**One additional comment: It's very important to respect the priority questionnaire < creation < buy. If the first event type that happens is the strongest ("buy"), then all following months will necessary be a "buy" type. A type cannot go to a lower type later on.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
with mytable as (
    select date '2021-05-01' as month, "questionnaire" as type, "email1@gmail.com" as email union all
    select date '2021-08-01' as month, "buy" as type, "email1@gmail.com" as email union all
    select date '2021-10-01' as month, "creation" as type, "email1@gmail.com" union all
    select date '2021-06-01' as month, "questionnaire" as type, "email2@gmail.com" as email union all
    select date '2021-08-01' as month, "creation" as type, "email2@gmail.com" as email union all
    select date '2021-10-01' as month, "buy" as type, "email2@gmail.com"
)
select 
  monthly as month,
  MIN(mytable.type) OVER (PARTITION BY emails.email ORDER BY monthly ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as computed_type,
  emails.email
from (select distinct email from mytable) as emails
cross join unnest(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY((select min(month) from mytable), current_date(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as monthly
left join mytable on emails.email = mytable.email and monthly = mytable.month
where true
qualify computed_type is not null
order by 3, 1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. How do you take into account the priorities between the different types though? In the query, it does not look like it's took into account, even if your result seems to be right

Comment: For example, the buy type can occur before the questionnaire type. If that's the case, then the type should still remain buy as it's stronger.

Comment: the MIN accounts the priorities

Comment: @NolwenBrosson it would be easier to answer if you explain your comment in the question description.

Comment: @sergeygeron , I don't understand how the MIN is able to account the priorities in your SQL query? How does it know the order questionnaire < creation < buy ?

Comment: Just updated the question with an additional comment on the priorities of type

Comment: string "buy" is considered lesser than string "creation" which itself is considered lesser than string "questionnaire" by BigQuery MIN function, therefore "buy" will have the highest priority with "creation" and "questionnaire" followed

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach - much cheaper, less verbose, etc.

```
select month, email, type
from (
  select *, ifnull(lead(month) over(partition by email order by month) - 1, current_date) next_month 
  from your_table 
), unnest(generate_date_array(month, next_month, interval 1 month)) month
order by email, month
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

```
month       email               type
2015-08-01  email1@gmail.com    questionnaire
2015-09-01  email1@gmail.com    questionnaire
2015-10-01  email1@gmail.com    questionnaire
2015-11-01  email1@gmail.com    questionnaire
2015-12-01  email1@gmail.com    questionnaire
2016-01-01  email1@gmail.com    questionnaire
2016-02-01  email1@gmail.com    questionnaire
2016-03-01  email1@gmail.com    questionnaire
2016-04-01  email1@gmail.com    questionnaire
2016-05-01  email1@gmail.com    questionnaire
2016-06-01  email1@gmail.com    questionnaire
2016-07-01  email1@gmail.com    questionnaire
2016-08-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2016-09-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2016-10-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2016-11-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2016-12-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2017-01-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2017-02-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2017-03-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2017-04-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2017-05-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2017-06-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2017-07-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2017-08-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2017-09-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2017-10-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2017-11-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2017-12-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2018-01-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2018-02-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2018-03-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2018-04-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2018-05-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2018-06-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2018-07-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2018-08-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2018-09-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2018-10-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2018-11-01  email1@gmail.com    creation
2018-12-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2019-01-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2019-02-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2019-03-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2019-04-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2019-05-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2019-06-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2019-07-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2019-08-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2019-09-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2019-10-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2019-11-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2019-12-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2020-01-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2020-02-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2020-03-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2020-04-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2020-05-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2020-06-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2020-07-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2020-08-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2020-09-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2020-10-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2020-11-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2020-12-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2021-01-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2021-02-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2021-03-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2021-04-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2021-05-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2021-06-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2021-07-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2021-08-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2021-09-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2021-10-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2021-11-01  email1@gmail.com    buy
2020-02-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2020-03-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2020-04-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2020-05-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2020-06-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2020-07-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2020-08-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2020-09-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2020-10-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2020-11-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2020-12-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2021-01-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2021-02-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2021-03-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2021-04-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2021-05-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2021-06-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2021-07-01  email2@gmail.com    questionnaire
2021-08-01  email2@gmail.com    creation
2021-09-01  email2@gmail.com    creation
2021-10-01  email2@gmail.com    creation
2021-11-01  email2@gmail.com    buy
```

Comment: Great! Probably we still need to replace `type` with `MIN(type) OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as type` in the outer `select` to respect the priorities mentioned. But this is much better indeed!